# Searching for files within a number of folders in command line in Windows 10

Tags: windows-10, command-line, dir, findstr

I'm trying to find the proper syntax for finding all the files with a specific name that are in a multitude of folders.  So - I have a directory with 100+ folders, in each folder there are files that are uniquely named but have a similar string in each name (AC_DATA).  I want to find the names and directories of all those AC_DATA* files.  I've tried many combinations, this one works if I have the name of the folder:

dir -r C:\DATA[foldername] /b | findstr /s /i  AC_DATA*

but this does not work when I want to find all the files that are in those folders. I need to find these files while not being in the C:\DATA\ directory.  I can do this in Windows 7 and unix but 10 is stumping me.

Comment: What is wrong with `dir /b /s AC_DATA*`?

Answer (score 0):

The correct syntax for searching from the command line is:

`dir /a /s <filename>` where `<filename>` is the name (or pattern - wildcards are accepted) of the file you're looking for.

`/a` lists all files including hidden and system files, and
`/s` searches the current directory and all subdirectories.  **NOTE** you must `CD` into the directory where you want to begin your search first.

Comment: That does work when changing to the search directory, it would be "ideal" if there was a way to find the files without changing directories, but I can work around that.  Thanks.